# ArayIndexOutOfBoundsException isn't working

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I have a problem with my codes here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class goTooFar {
    public static void main(String[] a){

        int i =4;
        int[] ar = new int[i];
        int n = i;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the size of an array: ");
        try {
            n = sc.nextInt();
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Now you have gone too far");
        }


        System.out.println("Enter " + n + " elements of an array: ");
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            try {
                ar[i] = sc.nextInt();
            } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Now you have gone too far");
            }
        System.out.println("Output Numbers: ");
            for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
                System.out.println(ar[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an input like this:

```
> Enter the size of an array: 
7

> Enter 7 elements of an array: 
1 4 2 5 3 9 0 7
```

But, it turns out to be like this:

```
>Output Numbers: 
1
0
0
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at goTooFar.main(goTooFar.java:31)
```

What can I do to fix this problem? Can someone help me? Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < n; i++){` ....

Comment: If you have `for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)` you have `n+1` iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the length of your array to 4 :

```
int i =4;
int[] ar = new int[i];
```

Therefore, when you input a longer array length, you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

You need to create the array after getting the length from the user :

```
System.out.println("Enter " + n + " elements of an array: ");
ar = new int[n]; // initialize a new array
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ // n is not a valid index for an array of length n
```

Also change the range of the other loop from

```
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        System.out.println(ar[i]);
    }
```

to

```
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        System.out.println(ar[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this part `for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)`

An array starts with the index 0. So if the size of the array is like in your case 7, then the highest index will be 6. (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)

You simply need the loop to check `i < n` instead.

in addition you initialized your array with a size of 4 before asking the user for the size of the array. Therefor you need to initialize with the array after the input happend

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
n = sc.nextInt();
```

to

```
n = sc.nextInt();
ar = new int[n];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Also the output for loop should be outside the input loop
`System.out.println("Output Numbers: ");
        for(int i = 0; i <n; i++){
            System.out.println(ar[i]);
        }`
The final code would be as follows:-

```
   int[] ar = null;
    int n = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the size of an array: ");
    try{
        n = sc.nextInt();
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Now you have gone too far");
    }

    ar = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " elements of an array: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        try{
            ar[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Now you have gone too far");
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Output Numbers: ");
    for(int i = 0; i <n; i++){
        System.out.println(ar[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem solved with this code... I used your code only...

```
public class goTooFar {

    public static void main(String[] a) {

        int i = 0, n = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of an array: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        int[] ar = new int[n];   // Problem 1 Fixed.

        System.out.println("Enter " + n + " elements of an array: ");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {           // Problem 2 fixed
                ar[i] = sc.nextInt();  // Enhancement 1         
        }
        System.out.println("Output Numbers: ");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(ar[i]);
        }
        sc.close(); // Enhancement 2
    }
}
```

List of **things you did wrong**... Where **modifications** are need to be done...

1. Initializing the array with 4 elements by default, then asking from user to enter how many elements he wants.
2. You are having n+1 iterations every time when you use `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)`... Instead use `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`...

**Not Problems... Enhancements...**

1. No need of `try-catch` unless you are doing something `**dangerous**`...
2. Always close your resources... its a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array after getting the value of variable n, and change your for loops range to from 0 to < n:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    int n = 0 ;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the size of an array: ");
    try{
        n = sc.nextInt();
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Now you have gone too far");
    }

    int [] ar = new int[n];  //declare the array after getting input from user about how many numbers will he enter

    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " elements of an array: ");   // change both loops to run from 0 to < n
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            ar[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Output Numbers: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            System.out.println(ar[i]);
        }    
}
```